# Не получается сделать нормально свертывание и развертывание строки в таблице

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$('.header').click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('expand')) {
    $(this).closest('table').find('.header').addClass('expand');
    $(this).closest('table').find('.child').remove();
    $(this).after('<tr class="child"><td colspan="5"><div class="content"><div class="col-xs-6"><p>Имя: Радбя</p><p>Телефон: 8955555555</p><p>email: </p><p>Пользователь: admin</p></div><div class="col-xs-6"><p>Информация: тиватитдвитваитвлтвадива</p></div><div class="col-xs-6"><p>Кол-во: 100</p><p>Приложение: нет</p><div class="col-xs-6"><p>Статус</p><p>Всего: 1000</p><p>Оплачено: 500</p></div></div></td></tr>').removeClass('expand');
    setTimeout(() => {
   $(this).parent().find('.child').addClass('animate');
    }, 0);    
  } else {
   $(this).addClass('expand').parent().find('.child').removeClass('animate');
    setTimeout(() => {
   $(this).parent().find('.child').remove();
    }, 500);      
  }
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td, th {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.header:hover{
  cursor: pointer
}
.header .sign:after{
  content: '-'
}
.header.expand .sign:after{
  content: '+'
}

.child div {
  height: 0em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.child.animate div {
  height: 2em;
  opacity: 1;
}


.child p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='0'>
  <tr>
    <th>Класс</th>
    <th>Код</th>
    <th>Город</th>
    <th>Дата создание</th>
    <th>Дата редактирование</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Мебель</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Казань</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:00:00</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Электроника</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Москва</td>
    <td>2017-03-15 09:15:00</td>
    <td>2017-03-15 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Бытовая химия</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Санк-Петербург</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:00:00</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

У меня развертыевает и сворачивает строка не получается нормально сделать, как-то он сплющено получается и некорректно выводит. Может кто-то подскажет как его перестроить?
Менять вешать собитии на p то немного тоже коряво получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .child.animate div {height: fit-content;}

```js
$('.header').after('<tr class="child"><td colspan="5"></td></tr>');

$('.header').click(function(){
   
  $(this).toggleClass('expand').next('.child').find("td").html('Контент<br/>Контент').slideToggle();
  
  $('.header.expand').not($(this)).toggleClass('expand').next('.child').find("td").slideToggle();


});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td, th{
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.child td{
    display:none;
}
.header .sign:before{
    content:"+";
    
}
.header.expand .sign:before{
    content:"-";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='0'>
  <tr>
    <th>Класс</th>
    <th>Код</th>
    <th>Город</th>
    <th>Дата создание</th>
    <th>Дата редактирование</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header'>
    <td class='sign'>Мебель</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Казань</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:00:00</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header'>
    <td class='sign'>Электроника</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Москва</td>
    <td>2017-03-15 09:15:00</td>
    <td>2017-03-15 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header'>
    <td class='sign'>Бытовая химия</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Санк-Петербург</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:00:00</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Там я как понимаю немного все равно не плавно https://jsfiddle.net/hollanditkzn/x2bcukw7/27/

Comment: А можно сделать еще плавнее сделать?

Comment: Просто если 2em то плавно идет, в отличии от такого подхода

Comment: @Руслан обновил ответ. правда код немного перелопатил, ваш избыточен.

Answer (score 0):

Для елемента .child.animate div сделайте высоту не 2em, а auto

Comment: ОНа тоже как-то не плавно а криво делается, лучш тогда сделать на p повесить. А есть какой-то такой плавный переход, чтобы еще текст вовромя исчезал или надо отдельно прописывать?